# Printing the value of a formula with openpyxl

Tags: excel, formula, openpyxl

I have been trying to research this for the past 2 days and the most regular answer I see is to use data_only=True however that does not seem to fix the issue of printing the value of a formula. Here is my scrip. Does anyone have an answer for this?

```
import os
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import csv
directoryPath = r'c:\users\username\documents\reporting\export\q3'
os.chdir(directoryPath)
folder_list = os.listdir(directoryPath)
for folders, sub_folders, file in os.walk(directoryPath):
    for name in file:
        if name.startswith("BEA"):
            filename = os.path.join(folders, name)
            print filename
            wb = load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
            sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sensor Status")
            for row_cells in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=4, min_col=8, max_col=13):
                for cell in row_cells:
                    print cell.internal_value
```

Comment: I would also like to mention when printing the cells with a formula just say 'none".

Comment: openpyxl will only print a value if another application has calculated one. PS. there is no need to use `cell.internal_value`